# Where is my BigQuery data is stored?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run a query on BigQuery from India, where is my file or data is stored. Is it in Asia region or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, BigQuery provides the option to specify one of two data locations (US & EU) when you create a dataset:

[image]

If you really want to have your data stored in the Asia region, a possible **workaround** would be to store/access all your data via federated sources i.e. as files in GCS. This is because GCS gives you the option to specify Asia as a region.

But, as fast as querying federated sources is, they will never perform as well as native BigQuery tables, latency etc.